# Using a Right Outer Join to Match Records from Two Different Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join

SQL 2005:

I am trying to create an outer join that will pull records from two different databases.  My objective is to determine which records in database B don't have matching records in database A.  When I tried running the query, it returned the error below.  I am not sure how to get around this error:

> 'Tables or functions 'AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable' and 'TA-Reporting.dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable' have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.'

```
          select * 
            from AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable
right outer join [database A].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable on
[database A].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable.AssetCompTypeID=
[database B].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable.AssetCompTypeID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you must differentiate between the tables. Try with:

```
select * 
from AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable T1
  right outer join 
    [database A].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable T2 
       on T1.AssetCompTypeID = T2.AssetCompTypeID
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign aliases:

```
 select * 
            from AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable tbl_thisDB
right outer join [database A].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable tbl_A on
tbl_A.AssetCompTypeID=
tbl_thisDB.AssetCompTypeID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use table aliases when JOINing tables with identical names, if not themselves:

```
          SELECT a.*, b.*
            FROM AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [database A].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable b ON a.AssetCompTypeID = b.AssetCompTypeID
```

It's necessary for the JOIN syntax alone, but additionally because you can't use `SELECT *` because of the likelihood of identical columns in the tables as well.

That said - to get the result you desire, you should consider:

### Using `NOT IN`

---

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM [database A].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable b
 WHERE b.AssetCompTypeID NOT IN (SELECT a.AssetCompTypeID
                                   FROM AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable a)
```

### Using `NOT EXISTS`

---

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM [database A].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable b
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable a
                    WHERE a.AssetCompTypeID = b.AssetCompTypeID)
```

### Using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`

---

```
   SELECT b.*
     FROM [database A].dbo.AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable b
LEFT JOIN AssetCompType_EquipmentProperty_LinkTable a ON a.AssetCompTypeID = b.AssetCompTypeID
    WHERE a.AssetCompTypeID IS NULL
```

### Conclusion

---

Of the three options, the `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are equivalent - the LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is less efficient.  See [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) for more details.

Comment: Actually, EXCEPT is probably the easiest way to do it (when the table definitions match) though not always the most efficient.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: `EXCEPT` also isn't ANSI

Comment: Not true, EXCEPT ***is*** in the standard.  I've got it right here in every edition of the standard that I have checked back to 2003 so far.  I can give you references if you want.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: If it is, SQL Server is the only DB I'm aware of that implements it.

Comment: Yes, it is, so good for SQL Server :-).  Fortunately it *is* a SQL Server question too.

Comment: @OMGPonies: `PostgreSQL` implements `EXCEPT` too (and it's only system of the major four than implements `EXCEPT ALL`). `Oracle` implements `MINUS`, which is just a synonym for `EXCEPT`.

Comment: @Quassnoi: How does the performance stack up against the NOT IN, LEFT JOIN IS NULL, NOT EXISTS in the DBs that support it?

Comment: @OMGPonies: In `SQL Server`, it is some flavor of an `ANTI JOIN` chosen by the optimizer. In `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL`, it is a special operation shown as such in the query plan. Essentially, this is a `MERGE ANTI JOIN` over the sorted sources.